# Change user password using cmd vbs or bat Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, cmd.exe, vbscript

Is there any command that I can use to change password to a user.
Something like a command that I type

```
change user1 oldpassword newpassword
```

Answer (score 1):

If you open up cmd as administrator and type in the following:

```
net user Peter password123
```

it will change the password from User *Peter* to *password123*

(Referring to the support of Microsoft itself:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/149427/how-to-change-user-password-at-command-prompt)

Comment: @qwqw Next time, show some effort and search for yourself: https://www.google.com/search?q=cmd+change+password&oq=cmd+change+password before you ask a question like that...

Comment: I need to do it without typing the password by my self. It should be in the file I will run

Comment: @qwqw Oh, you didn't said that. Can you be a bit more specific what the file does look like?

Comment: I just need any time of script that I will place on a usb flash drive and just go and run on every computer without typing any passwords, the passwords need to be in script
Thanks for your help

Comment: @qwqw Just put the line like you want it in a `.bat` file then.

Comment: @qwqw - Edit your question.  Noisy and unnecessary commentary will be reported and deleted.  You can easily turn this "command" into a script.  *You would just run the command within the script....*

Comment: Lets say, you have a file called password.txt that only contains the new password. You can then use `net user Peter < password.txt`

Comment: Or just put `net user Peter password123` into a batch file